# Return Data Row after Insert with ODBC

Tags: c#, postgresql, odbc

I am trying to figure out how to return row from an insert command using c# and ODBC when updating a postgresql database.  The table I'm inserting into has a user_id field that uses a sequence to auto-increment the value.  I'm looking to get at least the user_id value.

```
OdbcCommand addCMD = new OdbcCommand();
addCMD.Connection = odbcConn;
addCMD.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO ""users""(""username"") VALUES(?)";
addCMD.Parameters.Add("@username", OdbcType.Text).Value = username;
addCMD.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I know that `ExecuteNonQuery` returns the number of rows affected.  Is there a way to get the datarow or user_id field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [RETURNING](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/sql-insert.html)

```
addCMD.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO ""users""(""username"") VALUES(?) RETURNING user_id";
```

Comment: Use ExecuteScalar instead of ExecuteNonQuery and that should return the user_id.